# Codeigniter remove follow button after following user

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi I am able to display users friends on a page but when I into the friends profile I still see the follow button, is there anyway I can remove the button after following? I am using codeigniter. see code.

Model

```
public function get_friends($user_id = NULL){
    if ($user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id')){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('users');
    $this->db->join('friends', 'friends.user_id = users.user_id');
    $this->db->where('friends.user_id2', $user_id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array($user_id);
        }
}
```

Controller

```
public function view($user_id = NULL){
    $data['friends'] = $this->Friend_model->get_friends($user_id);  
    $this->load->view('user/templates/header_view_subpage');
    $this->load->view('user/members_entry_view', $data);
    $this->load->view('user/templates/footer_view_subpage');

}
```

View

```
<?php
     $session = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
     $friends = $this->session->userdata('user_id2');
     if($session == $members['user_id']):
?> 
    <div class="col-md-6">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-block"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Send Message</button>
    </div>
<?php 
endif;
?>
```

Comment: what is the array key to check following?

Comment: `$members['user_id']` not send from controller to view. `$data['friends']` and  `$friends = $this->session` is assign to same variable. Replace one of those. and try

Comment: the array used in the controller is $data['friends'] so in the friends list page I used foreach($friends as friend)... which works fine, but in the friend profile page I use the $friends variable without the foreach obviously, the thing is when you go into a users profile you would see the send message button and follow button but I want to remove the follow button for those who are friends of the user. If you can help that would be nice. Thanks

Comment: show us relevant follow button code

Comment: <div class="col-md-6">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-block"><i class="fa fa-add"></i> Follow</button>
    </div>

Comment: add the code in question with `print_r($friends)` array data

Comment: You will need to refresh the page after adding friend in order to re-render php code. If you don't want to refresh then you will need to make some ajax call and modify DOM

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to write a function that checks if a user is already a friend or not, something like this:

```
public function isFriend($id){
return $this->Friend_model->is_friend($user_id);  
}
```

the is_friend method will fetch the database and tries to fetch a user with the $user_id, if there is a record then our function will return true otherwise it will return false;

```
public function is_friend($user_id,$friend_id){ 
$this->db->select('*'); 
$this->db->from('friends');
$this->db->where('user_id',$user_id); 
$this->db->where('friend_id',$friend_id); 
$query = $this->db->get(); 
$results = $query->result_array(); 
return count($results) ? 1 : 0; 
}
```

After this we call the function in our view, if it returns true, then we don't show the button otherwise we show it.

Comment: Hi it's still giving me stress, I tried what you asked me to do but instead I get series of errors, the is_friend method in the model is joining the friends table with the users table which when run in mysql displays all the users with friends but I am struggling to display it in the view. do you think you can elaborate more on your solution? Thanks

Comment: okay, first thing first, what is the architecture of your tables, I think that you have something like: Users_table(ID,name,...etc) and Friends_table(ID,user_id,friend_id) right?

Comment: exactly, the friends table has no foreign key constraints

Comment: so in other words, if I want to check if a user is in another user friends list, I will check if there is a row like this Friends($my_user_id, $a_friend), right?

Comment: okay then, so the is_Friend function will be like:
public function is_friend($user_id,$friend_id){
$this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('friends');
$this->db->where('user_id',$user_id);
$this->db->where('friend_id',$friend_id);
$query = $this->db->get();
$results = $query->result_array();
return count($results) ? 1 : 0;
}

this will return 1 if that user is in our friend list otherwise it will return 0

Comment: Hi thank you so much for the clarity, I only have an issue now, so when I call the is_friend method in the controller I get an error. please see my code below

Comment: public function view($user_id2 = NULL){
   $data['friends'] = $this->Friend_model->is_friend($user_id2); 
   $this->load->view('user/templates/header_view_subpage');
   $this->load->view('user/test_friend_view', $data);
   $this->load->view('user/templates/footer_view_subpage');
   
  }

Comment: where user_id2 is what you call friend_id

Comment: Message: Call to undefined method Friend_model::is_friend()

Comment: I believe that error is just for calling the function, its not static, so call it using the operator ->

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: You're welcome, you can select the answer and up vote it :)

Comment: Will do, so in all this is how my view and model looks, please advise if this is right

Comment: Model 1 -  public function get_friends(){
  if ($user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id')){
  $this->db->select('*');
     $this->db->from('users');
     $this->db->join('friends', 'friends.user_id = users.user_id');
     $this->db->where('friends.user_id2', $user_id);
     $query = $this->db->get();
     return $query->result_array($user_id);
      }
  }

Comment: Model 2 public function is_friend($user_id, $user_id2){
  $this->db->select('*'); 
  $this->db->from('friends'); 
  $this->db->where('user_id',$user_id); 
  $this->db->where('user_id2',$user_id2); $query = 
  $this->db->get(); $results = $query->result_array(); 
  return count($results) ? 1 : 0;
 }

Comment: controller - public function view($user_id2, $user_id){
   $user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
   $data['friends'] = $this->Friend_model->is_friend($user_id, $user_id2); 
   $this->load->view('user/templates/header_view_subpage');
   $this->load->view('user/test_friend_view', $data);
   $this->load->view('user/templates/footer_view_subpage');
   
  }